# Async periodic task in nodejs

Tags: node.js, cloudinary

I am learning backend in nodejs. I am dealing with file upload. I accept a file using multer and store the file in the server disk storage and then by using this locally saved file, I upload it to cloudinary and unlink the locally saved file in upload success as well as upload failure. I am using fs/promises for file operations.

```
import { v2 as cloudinary } from "cloudinary";
import fs from "fs/promises";

cloudinary.config({
    cloud_name: process.env.CLOUDINARY_CLOUD_NAME,
    api_key: process.env.CLOUDINARY_API_KEY,
    api_secret: process.env.CLOUDINARY_API_SECRET,
});

const uploadToCloudinary = async (localFilePath) => {
    const uploadResult = { status: "error", uploadedFileDetails: {} };

    if (!localFilePath || typeof localFilePath !== "string") {
        console.error("Invalid local file path provided");
        return uploadResult;
    }

    try {
        await fs.access(localFilePath, fs.constants.F_OK);
    } catch (accessError) {
        console.error(
            `Local file does not exist or inaccessible : ${accessError.name} \n${accessError.message}`
        );
        return uploadResult;
    }

    try {
        const cloudinaryUploadResponse = await cloudinary.uploader.upload(
            localFilePath,
            { resource_type: "auto" }
        );
        uploadResult.status = "success";
        uploadResult.uploadedFileDetails.publicId =
            cloudinaryUploadResponse.public_id;
        uploadResult.uploadedFileDetails.url =
            cloudinaryUploadResponse.secure_url;
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(
            `Error occurred while uploading the file to cloudinary : ${error}`
        );
    } finally {
        try {
            await fs.unlink(localFilePath);
        } catch (unlinkingError) {
            console.error(
                `Error occurred while unlinking the local file : ${unlinkingError.name} \n${unlinkingError.message}`
            );
        }
    }

    return uploadResult;
};

const deleteFromCloudinary = async (publicId, resourceType = "image") => {
    const deleteResult = { status: "error" };

    if (!publicId || typeof publicId !== "string") {
        console.error("Invalid public ID provided");
        return deleteResult;
    }

    try {
        const cloudinaryDeleteResponse = await cloudinary.uploader.destroy(
            publicId,
            { resource_type: resourceType }
        );
        if (cloudinaryDeleteResponse.result === "ok") {
            deleteResult.status = "success";
        } else {
            console.error("Cloudinary deletion failed");
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(
            `Error occurred while deleting the file from cloudinary : ${error}`
        );
    }

    return deleteResult;
};

export { uploadToCloudinary, deleteFromCloudinary };
```

What should be done if there is an error in unlinking in uploadToCloudinary function?

I am thinking to periodically clean the temp directory

```
import fs from "fs/promises";
import path from "path";

const cleanupTempFiles = async () => {
    try {
        const TEMP_DIR = "./public/temp";
        const files = await fs.readdir(TEMP_DIR);
        const now = Date.now();
        const twentyFourHours = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;

        for (const file of files) {
            const filePath = path.join(TEMP_DIR, file);
            const fileStat = await fs.stat(filePath);
            if (
                file !== ".gitkeep" &&
                now - fileStat.birthtimeMs >= twentyFourHours
            ) {
                await fs.unlink(filePath);
            }
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(`Error occurred during cleanup: ${error}`);
    }
};

const scheduleCleanup = async () => {
    try {
        console.log("Clean up start");
        await cleanupTempFiles();
        console.log("Clean up end");
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(
            `Error occurred while periodic cleanup : ${error.name} \n${error.message}`
        );
    }
    finally {
        setTimeout(scheduleCleanup, 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
    }
};

export { scheduleCleanup };
```

Can someone pls tell me I am on right track or not?

Or should I do something else

Answer (score 0):

Rather than having a Node script running 24/7, the best thing to do would be to run cron to clear out the contents of your temporary directory. I shan't give an exact example, as the usage will depend on your use-case, but there are plenty of examples of how to do this on StackOverflow/Google/search-engine-of-your-choice.